# How to do Application to application (server to server) authentication, OAuth 2.0, Web API 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, restful-authentication

I'm on a project that has 2 separate ASP.NET MVC 5 Applications. One uses the other as a service. Basically, one of the applications is a Profile Service that has all the profile information of users so that, in the future, other applications can use that service and users don't have to set up multiple accounts. These applications are internal to the organization. For authentication and authorization, we use Windows authentication and smart cards. The profile service app uses Web API 2.0. I have not set up OAuth 2.0 yet.

**The problem:** as it stands now, anyone who knows how to send a request to profile service can do so (like typing in a url with query strings).

**What I'm trying to achieve:** I want to authorize my other application (for now, only that one... in the future, more). I do not want the requests to be based on the authorization of the users using the application, but the application itself. In other words, if the request to profile service comes from that application, regardless of who is logged in and using it, the profile service takes that as an authorize request... if it comes from anywhere else, it's denied.

I have already done some research. I can't find anything that clearly states how to set this up. I have found stuff on how to make your app authorized for Google Services or Twitter services specifically... that tells me how to set up the client application, not the server application (but even the client setup I'm not sure would be correct for my specific needs, since it's an internal app, since I don't know how the Google services work, etc). It seems OAuth 2.0 and tokens are the way to go, but how do I implement this? I need really specific, step-by-step answers (hopefully with some code).

Thank you so much in advance. I will be checking back in frequently. Let me know if you need more info.

Edit:
Oh! I forgot to mention! We're using HTTPS, not HTTP... does this have any bearing?

Answer (score 5):

OAuth has different grant types, the one you need is "client credentials" to authorize the application itself.  This is different from the ones you see for google/facebook, since there is no redirect/browser interaction.

```
POST https://oauthEndpointurl/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
```

Client ID and Client Secret is sent to the server and then the token is returned and possibly a refresh token depending on you're implementation.

Then you all you need to do is send the token back in the header of the request.  (if you're using a library then it's handled already.)

```
"Authorization: Bearer xxxxTOKENxxxxx"
```

Checkout this article on DO for more details:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll let you know how this goes and if I have further questions. I tried to add a point to your answer but I don't have enough rep yet for it to show. Also, if anyone has anything they'd like to add, I'd be really happy to read more... Oh! I forgot to mention! We're using HTTPS, not HTTP... does this have any bearing?

Comment: nope, https is fine should be anyway.  Since you didn't mention a specific Oauth library i couldn't really be too specific but this is the basics of it.   if there is anything more specific let me know, it's sort of a generic answer but it's also simple once you understand how it works then you can pick what works for you're scenario.    you can also use json web tokens as well along with Oauth.

Comment: Do you think that OAuth2 is definitely the way to go with this? I've spoken to the senior developer on my team and he says, since these are internal applications and there isn't too much risk involved, we can use an individual account (like with a regular user name and password) and just hard code that into the client application. What do you think? If we are going to do it this way, what framework would you suggest and how should we go about it? Thanks so much. Sorry to trouble you again.

Comment: The only real benefit to Oauth over simple authentication is that it allows you to wire up revokable tokens, the primary benefit being when you have external clients or you're on a public facing network so that a poached token (which can be snooped from a browser even over a secure connection) can't be used. Client credentials on a front end are easy; it's the work of setting them up on the back end which makes it overkill in this simple case.

Comment: Thanks so much Jeff. Yeah, I was starting to think maybe OAuth wasn't the way to go here, so I'm glad you confirmed it for me. Any suggestions on how to move forward? I'm kind of an authentication and authorization idiot, but I've got to figure it out because I'm the only developer assigned to this project for this sprint. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out.